# Trying to delete folders with Unicode names

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, unicode

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
     print 'Need to force directories into sys.argv'

     #sys.argv += ["C:\Users\Andy\Desktop"]
     #sys.argv += ["C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\Webpages"]
     sys.argv += ["C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\Downloads (2)"]

def removeEmptyFolders(path):
  if not os.path.isdir(path):
    return

  # remove empty subfolders
  files = os.listdir(path)
  if len(files):
    for f in files:
      fullpath = os.path.join(path, f)
      if os.path.isdir(fullpath):
        removeEmptyFolders(fullpath)

  # if folder empty, delete it
  files = os.listdir(path)
  if len(files) == 0:
    print "Removing empty folder:", path
    os.rmdir(path)

for x in sys.argv[1:]:
     print 'Scanning directory "%s"....' % x
     removeEmptyFolders(x)
     print 'Done.'
```

I'm trying to use this code to delete empty folders, but it doesn't detect folders with characters like » and ▶...

I've tried enclosing all my path variables in unicode(), but that returns things like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 37, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 27, in removeEmptyFolders
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 27, in removeEmptyFolders
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 32, in removeEmptyFolders
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\bin\2.7\src.zip\debug\tserver\dbgutils.py", line 1491, in write
UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp932' codec can't encode character u'\xbb' in position 54: illegal multibyte sequence
```

I've done

```
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

But that doesn't help either. Without the Unicode()-s, it just gets me:

```
Need to force directories into sys.argv
Scanning directory "C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\Downloads (2)"....
Done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\Delete Empty Folders.py", line 959, in <module>
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute '_FixGetPass'
```

And with the Unicode()-s... it's the same as without the default encoding change.

Note: I's using Wing IDE.

Should I just switch to Python 3?

Comment: So what code do you have in `dbgutils` that triggers the encoding error? Why is that function involved at all? Using unicode is exactly what *this function* should be using.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I haven't done _anything_ with dbgutils... I don't even know what it is... other than most likely: "Debug Utilities"...

Comment: Right, is it a debugger tool of your IDE perhaps? You didn't include the full traceback here so I cannot even begin to help debug that issue.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Added the full Traceback...

Comment: Your `print "Removing empty folder:", path` line causes that; just encode your Unicode string there or use `repr(path)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `unicode` for the paths is the correct solution; if you pass in a `unicode` value to `os.listdir()` it'll produce `unicode` filenames, and everything works as it should.

Your traceback is actually caused by your `print` statement:

```
print "Removing empty folder:", path
```

which WingIDE tried to encode for network use, and that failed as your system encoding (Codepage 932) cannot encode some of the characters in your paths.

You can work around that part by using `repr()` instead:

```
print "Removing empty folder:", repr(path)
```

as this at the very least gives you a debuggable representation of the path with any non-printable non-ASCII characters replaced by escape codes.

Comment: Yes... that works for the Unicode()-s... which is all I need to get it to work... but, do you know what the FixGetPass from the default encoding change is about?

Comment: @Malandy What is on line 959 of your script? The version you pasted doesn't have nearly that many lines.

Comment: @Malandy: I don't know; that happens *outside* of the code you posted here. Somewhere after your code prints `Done.`.

Comment: @Random832 - There isn't a line 959... the code is only 38 lines or so... Perhaps it's a line at 959 mod <code length>... but the code works... and the error's too weird, so I'm not bothering to find the reason _that_ much...

Comment: @Malandy: no, Python doesn't work that way; I cannot see your file so I cannot help figure that one out. Does opening it in another editor show anything unexpected? What does `print sum(1 for _ in open(r'C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\Delete Empty Folders.py', 'rb'))` produce (run from another Python script perhaps).

Comment: @Malandy See if it still happens if you run the script on the command line and not in the IDE.

Comment: @Random832 - I ran with Python.exe and it exited without crashing... - The result of the print statement from Martijn gets 38, meaning 38 lines, I assume...

Comment: @Malandy probably a bug in Wing IDE then.